# Is it possible to apply an other tag to a dependency role?

Tags: ansible, role

I have a playbook like that, with one role per client.

```
- hosts: hosting
  roles:
    - { role: client1, tags: ['client1'] }
    - { role: client2, tags: ['client2'] }
```

And on each role, I have a dependency on nginx for example.

```
/roles/client1/meta/main.yml
dependencies:
  - nginx
```

I would like to **not launch** the nginx role when it is not necessary. So I have added the nginx tag to the dependency.

```
/roles/client1/meta/main.yml
dependencies:
  - { role: nginx, tags: ['system'] }
```

But when I launch the playbook with the tag client1, the nginx role is executed.
Is there a solution to avoid that ?

I know a can "export" the dependency on the playbook, it works good, but it's not a nice solution I think.

```
- hosts: hosting
  roles:
    - { role: nginx, tags: ['system'] }
    - { role: client1, tags: ['client1'] }
    - { role: client2, tags: ['client2'] }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tags do not override each other but are cummulative. Your dependency now has the tags `client1` and `system`.

But that already is enough. Just tell Ansible to skip the system tag when calling your playbook:

```
ansible-playbook ... --tags client1 --skip-tags system
```